# Error: Estas credenciales no coinciden con nuestros registros en reestablecimiento de contraseña Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, formularios, laravel-blade, hash

Tras configurar el reenvío de contraseña en un proyecto de Laravel 5.6, puedo enviar a través de una cuenta de gmail el correo, recibo en la bandeja de entrada el aviso, me lleva correctamente el enlace correspondiente a la vista y puedo renovar mi contraseña de usuario, iniciando de forma automática la sesión con el mismo a continuación. Puedo trabajar con el usuario sin problema. 
Sin embargo, en cuanto se cierra sesión e intento acceder con ese mismo email, me dice: "Estas credenciales no coinciden con nuestros registros".
Pensé que había algún error en la BD, pero el usuario aparece correctamente en ella y la contraseña y token hasheados.
Se supone que todo este proceso es automático, pero no consigo ver el error....

La función para crear nuevos usuarios dentro del UserController es esta:

```
public function newRegister(Request $request){
        $validate = $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'surname1' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'surname2' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'role' => 'required|string|max:20',     
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',   
        ]);

        $remember_token = $request->input('remember_token');

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'surname1' => $request['surname1'],
            'surname2' => $request['surname2'],
            'role' => $request['role'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'password' => \Hash::make($request['password']),
            'remember_token'=> $remember_token ,
            ]);
         $user= User::where('name', '=', $request['name'] )->first();

        $user->remember_token = $remember_token;

        $user->update();
             return redirect()->route('user.newUser')
                    ->with(['message'=>'USUARIO CREADO CORRECTAMENTE']);
    }//fin newRegister
```

Es el único punto donde pienso que puede haber algún error, teniendo en cuenta la automatización del resto...

Comment: He visto en comentarios de preguntas similares posibles conflictos de "doble hash", y ya que tengo el csrf en el formulario, probé a quitar el hash en la encriptación desde el controlador, pero entonces, me guarda el dato visible. Creo sin embargo, que el error tiene que ir por ese lado, pero no soy capaz a ver en que punto es mejor tirar un dd y ver si es cierto...sigo probando, pero agradeceré cualquier comentario o pista que ayude en la resolución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por suerte en buena parte, y por la cantidad de material que afortunadamente hay por la red, encontré un vídeo donde completaban en el archivo .env dos campos que yo mantenía por defecto

```
MAIL_FROM_ADRESS= micorreoejemplo@correo.es
MAIL_FROM_NAME= Jag
```

Yo los agregué para poder mejorar la presentación en el envío del correo que solicitaba el restablecimiento de password, que por defecto se encabezaba con un Example.
Sólo con esa modificación, me guarda y restablece perfectamente a un usuario.
Agradeceré, eso sí, si alguno de la comunidad puede decirme el porqué....
Seguimos avanzando!

Answer (score 0):

El error es que tienes que ingresar al sistema donde este tú correo afiliado en el telefono o computador, así se sincroniza

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)